# Display total records found - php

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Well i have a query which gives me couple of records.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE..... LIMIT $limit";//getting dynamic limit values.
```

This gives me.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE..... LIMIT 61,10";
$res=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs=parent::getAll($res);
return $rs;
```

Here total records found is 61, out of which only just 10 record is returning. I need to display the total record. i,e **61** in my HTML file.

How do i able to get the total records?

Comment: remove your limit from your query. that will display entire result.

Comment: Limit is needed for my pagination.

Comment: then you have to use two query one for count result and second for listing. if you need to show all result remove limit from your query or limit 0,total result

Comment: you can add select count(*) to the start of your select and ask that SELECT COUNT( * ), * FROM tablename ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to limit the result set using LIMIT you'll have to run a second separate query along the lines of "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE...". Either that or just remove the LIMIT.